# feeds importer only reading first 240 of csv

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

Using Feeds to upload a very simple csv of Node title and body fields, via the one time import form. It is only loading the first 250 rows regardless of the setting. I have tried adding `$conf['feeds_process_limit']` to my setting file, but it's not working.

`$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 100;`
will result in 250 being loaded

`$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 1000;`
will result in 250 being loaded.

Any ideas? I have tried moving around items in my csv so I know it's not bad data that is screwing up the works. I never get any other errors, or anything in the log.

thanks,
summer

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the process in background option? If so, run cron to complete the import. Else, try the dev version of Feeds. In there the UX on this part has been improved. Feeds will for example say that you need to run cron to continue the import.